# How do I enable XRandR in Xvfb or disable it in firefox when running firefox headless?

Tags: firefox, xorg, sh, xvfb

I am trying to start firefox headless.  The following is the beginning of the shell script that starts it:

```
#!/bin/sh
Xvfb :99 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
XVFB=$!
sleep 3
firefox --display=:99 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
FIREFOX=$!
```

When this script is run, the following error occurs:

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
```

I have tried starting Xvfb with the following, but it does not prevent the error:

```
Xvfb -extension RANDR :99 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

and

```
Xvfb +extension RANDR :99 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Is there a better way to enable XRandR in Xvfb so that firefox is able to see the extension?

Alternatively, is there a way to disable XRandR in firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox now has a [headless mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Headless_mode) which doesn't require an X server (like Xvfb) at all. If you're reading this, you may want to investigate this as an alternative, as it's much simpler to work with.

Comment: `/path/to/firefox -headless`

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/12/using-headless-mode-in-firefox/

Answer (score 0):

Xvfb dose not implement Xrandr, the only way to enable is would be to implement it. So in that case just ignore this message or filter it out. Like

```
firefox | grep -v RANDR
```

or so...

Comment: or maybe not, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644001/how-to-add-the-missing-randr-extension